# jquery ajax post callback - manipulation stops after the "third" call

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

**EDIT**: The problem is not related to Boxy, I've run into the same issue when I've used JQuery 's load method.

**EDIT 2**: When I take out `link.remove()` from inside the ajax callback and place it before ajax load, the problem is no more. Are there restrictions for manipulating elements inside an ajax callback function.

I am using JQuery with Boxy plugin.

When the 'Flag' link on the page is clicked, a Boxy modal pops-up and loads a form via ajax. When the user submits the form, the link (`<a>` tag) is removed and a new one is created from the ajax response. This mechanism works for, well, 3 times! After the 3rd, the callback function just does not remove/replace/append (tested several variations of manipulation) the element.

The only hint I have is that after the 3rd call, the parent of the link becomes non-selectable. However I can't make anything of this.

Sorry if this is a very trivial issue, I have no experience in client-side programming.

The relevant html is below:

```
<div class="flag-link">
    <img class="flag-img" style="width: 16px; visibility: hidden;" src="/static/images/flag.png" alt=""/>
    <a class="unflagged" href="/i/flag/showform/9/1/?next=/users/1/ozgurisil">Flag</a>
</div>
```

Here is the relevant js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('div.flag-link a.unflagged').live('click', function(e){   
        doFlag(e);
        return false;
    }); 
...

});


function doFlag(e) {
   var link = $(e.target);
   var url = link.attr('href');

   Boxy.load(url, {title:'Inappropriate Content', unloadOnHide:true, cache:false, behaviours: function(r) {
    $("#flag-form").live("submit", function(){

        var post_url = $("#flag-form").attr('action');
        boxy = Boxy.get(this);
        boxy.hideAndUnload();
        $.post(post_url, $("#flag-form").serialize(), function(data){

            par = link.parent();                
            par.append(data);
            alert (par.attr('class')); //BECOMES UNDEFINED AT THE 3RD CALL!!
            par.children('img.flag-img').css('visibility', 'visible');
            link.remove();                                              
        });

        return false;
        }); 
    }});

}
```

Comment: Why do you remove/replace the link? can't you just update the link's href and class atrributes? That would be a much safer thing to do.

Comment: I will try to provide a demo. Replacing the link was trouble-free before I ran into this. This is the first time that I attempted to replace the element within an ajax callback function though. I recently made an edit, btw.

Comment: Regarding your edit, you'd have to debug to see what's really going on in the document, what is getting inserted/removed (for instance, it is not clear what data contains inside the callback).

Comment: The browser just stops to do what it has done after the 3rd repeat. I debugged the code (too many times) and I can say that the response data is definitely as I expected. Also no exceptions are raised through the execution. In short, everything seems OK.

Comment: By the way, I changed the code so that I update href and class of the link. It works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Old and late reply, but.. I found this while googling for my answer, so.. :)

I think this is a problem with the "notmodified" error being thrown, because you return the same Ajax data.

It seems that this is happening even if the "ifModified" option is set to false (which is also the default).

Returning the same Ajax data three times will cause issues for me (jQuery 1.4). Making the data unique (just adding time/random number in the response) removes the problem.

I don't know if this is a browser (Firefox), jQuery or server (Apache) issue though..

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, I could not run javascript after I call boxy. So I put all my javascript code in afterShow:function one of boxy attributes. I can run almost except submit my form. My be my way can give you something.